# A nice 5x5 word square

Tags: word, word-square, crossword-clues

Clues:

1. type of Indian cows;
2. what's done to money;
3. needs a good groom;
4. more than deserved;
5. needs a good groom.

Construct the word square! (I created it myself; hoping the above is enough info to solve it.)

Comment: No clue. Perhaps #2 is (rot13)fcraq?

Comment: @Red nope, sorry.

Comment: Heh, I like how clues 3 and 5 work!

Comment: Don't forget to mark one as correct ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grid

> ```
> ZEBUS
> EARNT
> BRIDE
> UNDUE
> STEED
> ```

Solving process

> My initial read on "needs a good groom" was something to do with hair (not far off from STEED). I looked for common Indian cow types that could be crossword grade, and found ZEBU, which could pluralize to ZEBUS. Then I went and googled "needs a good groom" and immediately BRIDE fell. Eventually ended up grepping U?D?? to get UNDUE, which made E?RN? something like EARNS or so, but that makes the fifth word weird. EARNT sounds like it could more or less fit the tense, let's check the defintion, alright it works. And finally, going back to the hair thought, STEED seems like the best fit.

Comment: You got it! I'm actually surprised it was so easy. Any insights on solving process? I'm curious which clues were the easiest to latch onto.

Answer (score 3):

The answer appears to be:

> ```
> ZEBUS
> EARNT
> BRIDE
> UNDUE
> STEER
> ```

Comment: Wow, nice! All correct except for the bottom right corner (I think a different letter there would fit the clue better). Any insights on solving process? I'm curious which clues were the easiest to latch onto.